# AWS Wordpress Site Crashed

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

Site was working fine this morning and now just a white screen after about a 45 second load.  Latency is super high and saw a huge spike in database requests before crash.  Here is some info from the error log:

```
[Tue Jan 20 19:35:35.758727 2015] [:error] [pid 5259] [client 10.164.61.169:9962] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/app/current/content/themes/thereserve/_modules/z_interactive_map/_admin/settings-properties.php on line 217
[Tue Jan 20 19:35:35.761324 2015] [:error] [pid 5259] [client 10.164.61.169:9962] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/app/current/content/themes/thereserve/_modules/z_interactive_map/_admin/settings-properties.php on line 217
[Tue Jan 20 19:41:34.521481 2015] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1867] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Tue Jan 20 20:53:29.784736 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1867] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Jan 20 20:53:34.308282 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1867] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jan 20 20:53:34.344476 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1867] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jan 20 20:53:34.427428 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1867] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 20 20:53:34.427451 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1867] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: could u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the "server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting" is a little alarming. I can't answer why that happens, but that might be the result of another problem.

If hitting the MaxRequestWorkers setting itself is not the RESULT of another problem but the problem itself, you can raise the "MaxRequestWorkers" ceiling in /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf, then restart Apache.